# Find and Replace Dates in a Word Document with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having an issue finding any date in the format "August 16, 2017" in the text of a Word document. Using ActiveDocument.Content.Find, I am only able to find results on the first page. Even within the first page, the results are inconsistent. Here is my code below.

```
Dim myMonth(1 To 12) As String
myMonth(1) = "January"
myMonth(2) = "February"
myMonth(3) = "March"
myMonth(4) = "April"
myMonth(5) = "May"
myMonth(6) = "June"
myMonth(7) = "July"
myMonth(8) = "August"
myMonth(9) = "September"
myMonth(10) = "October"
myMonth(11) = "November"
myMonth(12) = "December"

'Find and replace dates in MMMM dd, yyyy format
For i = 12 To 1 Step -1
    With ActiveDocument.Content
    With .Find
        .Text = "(" & myMonth(i) & ")" & " ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    While .Find.Execute
        .Text = CDate(.Text) + 7
        .Text = Format(.Text, "mmmm d, yyyy")

    Wend
        .Find.MatchWildcards = False
    End With

    Next i
```

This code adds 7 days to any date in said format. I have tried looping through all stories, and the result was the same. I have been able to perform this task for dates in the format "08/16/2017", so the problem seems to lie in the extra For loop for each month. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you do not need an array of monthnames. there is a built-in function you can use `monthname(10)`

Comment: Word's `Find` and `Selection` interact in complex ways, see e.g. [here](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/words_fickle_vba_find_property.html). It might help to move the selection back to the top of the document with `Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory` at the start of the For loop.

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but you're using `Format` on text, when it should be used on a numeric value. I'd recommend something like `myDate = CDate(.Text) + 7`, then `.Text = Format(myDate, "mmmm d, yyyy")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
Sub findMe()

    Dim aaa As Find
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 12
        Debug.Print MonthName(i)

        Set aaa = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=1, End:=1).Find    ' start at beginning of document

        aaa.ClearFormatting
        aaa.Replacement.ClearFormatting

        aaa.Forward = True
        aaa.Wrap = wdFindStop
        aaa.Format = False
        aaa.MatchCase = False
        aaa.MatchWholeWord = False
        aaa.MatchAllWordForms = False
        aaa.MatchSoundsLike = False
        aaa.MatchWildcards = True
        aaa.Replacement.Text = ""

        ' search text starts with any character so that upper case and lower case words are found .... july July
        aaa.Text = "?" & Mid(MonthName(i), 2, 20) & "[ ^t]{1,5}([0-9]{1,2}),[ ^t]{1,5}([0-9]{4})"

        Do While True
            DoEvents
            If Not aaa.Execute Then Exit Do                    ' find next

            Debug.Print aaa.Parent.Text                        ' found text 
            Debug.Print Format(aaa.Parent.Text, "mm/dd/yy")    ' reformat date
            Debug.Print DateAdd("d", 7, aaa.Parent.Text)       ' add 7 days
            Debug.Print Format(DateAdd("d", 7, aaa.Parent.Text), "mmmm dd, yyyy")

            ' aaa.Parent is the range object of the found text
            ' so you can do this ...
            aaa.Parent.Text = Format(DateAdd("d", 7, aaa.Parent.Text), "mm/dd/yy")
            aaa.Parent.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd           ' point to "just after replaced text"

        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This was able to select all the dates. The DateAdd function did not work for me though. It looks like I will have to change to "mm/dd/yy" format to mark a date as changed, then do a new search to reformat the dates. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what you want to do makes no sense. why do search twice? what version of ms word do you have?

Comment: saying _The DateAdd function did not work for me though._ does not give any information. what happened?

Comment: My understanding is that if you do not change the date to a different format, this code would continue to change the dates forever in a loop. The DateAdd function did not add 7 days - it did nothing.

Comment: your dates are still in the long date format?  _August 16, 2017_

Comment: Your code changed all the dates to mm/dd/yy format, without adding 7 days to them.

Comment: look at the line at bottom ` aaa.Parent.Text = ...`  does it have DateAdd ?  i think that i originally posted without a date add. the addition was done in  the debug.print line. i thought that you would spend some time examining the code, and you would put the dateAdd in yourself. i have since updated the code